# How to parse an array with a neural network in python using keras?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

I am wondering how to make a minimal neural network capable of associating the content of an array with an output value, to then be able to predict the same thing but for other arrays. When I tested it using an array of one row and one neuron for each input data in the first layer it worked correctly, but when using an array of several rows I get errors.

I attach my code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense

s1 = np.array([[1,1,1],
               [0,0,0],
               [1,1,1]])


s2 = np.array([[1,0,1],
               [1,0,1],
               [1,0,1]])

s3 = np.array([[1,1,1],
               [1,1,1],
               [1,1,1]])

s4 = np.array([[0,0,0],
               [0,1,0],
               [0,0,0]])
training_data = np.array([s1,s2,s3,s4])



target_data = np.array([[0],[0],[1],[1]], "float32")

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_dim=(len(s1[:,0])*len(s1[0,:])), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['binary_accuracy'])

model.fit(training_data, target_data, epochs= 43)

# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(training_data, target_data)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % ("Efectividad", scores[1]*100))

#prediction of future values
eject =  np.array([[1,1,1],
                   [0,1,0],
                   [1,1,1]])



print (model.predict(eject).round())
```

Comment: please add your error messages

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible problems in your code:
if you are not able to train your model then you can try with using flatten() as a first input layer.

like

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['binary_accuracy'])

model.fit(training_data, target_data, epochs= 43)

# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(training_data, target_data)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % ("Efectividad", scores[1]*100))
```

and if the error has occured at the time of prediction then this would be because model.predict() method expects a batch as input not a single instance so in your case you need to reshape your eject array as follows:

```
eject =  np.array([[1,1,1],
               [0,1,0],
               [1,1,1]])
eject=eject.reshape(1,3,3)
print (model.predict(eject))
```